# How to use Microsoft Agent

Tags: c#, microsoft-agent

do u know guys how to make the Microsoft Agent takes my voice and understand it and put the words into text or string ?

i really could manage to make Microsoft Agent speak the text i gave him ,but i couldn't do the opposite .

thanx all ready for the answers

Answer (score 1):

Agents don't do speech recognition.
You should use Speech SDK to do speech recognition.
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/021126.htm

Above article should help you out.

Comment: More accurately, MSAgent only supports **basic** speech recognition.  It can only recognize speech commands that you pre-define in your code that is interacting with the character.  You cannot do general purpose speech recognition with MSAgent